# how can i exclude a single .yml file from a single file publish?

Tags: c#, yaml

i tried:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="config.yml">
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
      <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

also tried the below:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="config.yml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

i also tried replacing the **PreserveNewest** with **true**

neither work, it still bundles it inside the .exe file

Comment: I'm assuming your target framework here is Asp.NET CORE?

Comment: it's a .NET console application

Comment: I just edited my answer based on your comment. let me know if that works

Comment: i tried it, but it didn't work

Comment: You can have a .Net Core Console application  or you can have a .Net Console application there is a difference. Which exact framework and version are you utilizing ?

Comment: this one says it can run on .NET Core on Windows, Linux, and macOS. i'm using .NET 5.0

Comment: under properties > application it just says Console Application though

Comment: Please look at my answer i added a screen shot of how to find your target framework

Comment: target framework is .NET 5.0

Answer (score 0):

If this is a Visual Studio Web Site Project

```
    <ProjectGroup>
        <!-- Exclude Files -->
        <ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>appConfiguration.json;*.yml</ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>
        
        <!-- Exclude Folders -->
        <ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>temp;otherfolder</ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>
    </ProjectGroup>
</Project>
```

Refrence : https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2020/Jul/25/Excluding-Files-and-Folders-in-Visual-Studio-Web-Site-Project

As per Microsoft documentation for Asp.Net 4 the structure of the .wpp.targets file looks like  :

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" 
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>   
    <ExcludeFromPackageFolders Include="[semi-colon-separated folder list]">
      <FromTarget>[arbitrary metadata value]</FromTarget>
    </ExcludeFromPackageFolders>
    <ExcludeFromPackageFiles Include="[semi-colon-separated file list]">
      <FromTarget>[arbitrary metadata value]</FromTarget>
    </ExcludeFromPackageFiles>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/advanced-enterprise-web-deployment/excluding-files-and-folders-from-deployment

Edit : after your comment can you try :

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Update="*.yml">
    <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

keep it like *.yml

To find your framework : click on your project folder in solution explorer then go to properties you will see [image]